# How to get desktop version of the site?

Tags: python, python-requests, python-requests-html

I am using the `requests` library to parse the website but it returns the mobile version of the site. How can I get the HTML page of the desktop version?

```
import requests

sess = requests.Session() 
sess.get("https://google.com/")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
session = HTMLSession()
session.headers['user-agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.97 Safari/537.36'
response = session.get(url, headers=session.headers)
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see that google gets a `User-Agent` header specifying the browser, from the inspect element of my Mozilla I can see that google gets

`User-Agent Mozilla/5.0 etc..`

Maybe you can try to send a header tricking Google to think it's being accessed from a browser.

Comment: I tried "headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}
"  but it did not help